# How in livewire get current url of app for menu active element

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

In which way can I define in laravel 7 with livewire 1.3 / turbolinks:5.2 / alpine@v2
current url of app for selecting current menu item(blade/bootstrap 4) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```html
<li class="{{ Request::is('products*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ route('products.index') }}"><span>Products</span></a>
    ....
</li>
```